# How to monitor remote servers using Cacti without SSH tunnels?

Tags: php, shell, monitoring, nagios, cacti

Nagios uses NRPE plugin to monitor remote processes.
So you need to open only one port on the remote machine.

For Cacti, you need to open all the required ports so the shell scripts can retrieve data.
Or we can use SSH tunneling.

Is there a NRPE equivalent for Cacti so remote monitor can be done securely?

Answer (score 0):

Cacti was really intended to work with SNMP, so there isn't an elegant solution to this.

However: you're free to use NRPE in conjunction with cacti. It seems a bit weird at first, but it definitely works.